# Exact center of a pixel-sized element in fluid layout Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I am still relatively new to fluid designs, so hopefully I am not just missing the obvious here after a bit of fumbling...

How do you get a 512x512 div element to be horizontally centered in a container-fluid Twitter Bootstrap layout. (There are fluid elements that adjust to screen-size on top.)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `fluid-row` container to wrap your centered element. This will go somewhere inside your `container-fluid` Apply auto left- and right-margins and a fixed width of 512px for your div.

HTML:

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="centered512px">
         <h2>512 px Centered DIV</h2>
         <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.centered512px {
    width: 512px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background-color: red;
}
```